# Display image in area touch with finger on the screen

Tags: android, android-imageview

When I touch a region on my screen, I want an `ImageView` to be visible at the touch area. An example of imageview is as follows.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

How can I set the image at region touch on the screen using the method below. Also when I tap on a new region the previous image become invisible.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, view) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    final int x = (int) event.getX();
    final int y = (int) event.getY();
    boolean result = false;
}
```

Comment: draw the image to the canvas using x and y and call invalidate to refresh your draw

Comment: my activity is a normal activity not a canvas

Comment: not enough time i am using a webview

Answer (score 1):

Use Canvas you will get the xy coordinates and you can easily get Imageview at that coordinates

Comment: with on touch we can't get it fast ?

Comment: Go through an Simple Canvas example in android you will get it

Comment: i never wrote a canvas before. i need to understand it then do the thing but it will take times. and i don't have

Comment: Get the concepts clear first Because it very important now as well as in future whenever you need it